# Order by meta_key where value is serialized

Tags: meta-value

I'd order post by meta_key but i've a problem with meta_value because is serialized object.

I'd order my post per count value.

```
a:2:{s:5:"count";d:9750;s:7:"timeout";i:1358466733;}
```

I use below code but order correctly until wp version 3.4.2 after update to 3.5 order by date:

```
 if (have_posts()) :
    $args=array(
    'meta_key' => 'tweets_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'showposts' => 10,
      ); 
      query_posts($args);
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//loop
```

stamp request:

```
REQUEST:SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, however your question is not really precise.

What you experience is probably already that it is possible to sort by `meta_key` even the value of it is a string of some serialized data - it's just that this *is* the standard binary sort and Wordpress does not take care about that this is a string with serialized data - it's just a string for the sort.

So the answer is: Yes, but this is not what you ask for.

Next to that answer, there is no feature built into Wordpress so far to search for some value inside a `meta_value` and then sort for that (sub) value.

It is required that you first get the whole result-set and then sort the data your own. This depends a bit on how you want to use it (you have not shared any code, so it is hard to say), technically there are multiple ways to do so.

Comment: I use a following code but works only until 3.4.2 version. if (have_posts()) : 
   $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'meta_key' => 'tweets_count',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   );
            query_posts($args);
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  // loop 
           endif;

Comment: You should edit your question and put that information in there. Also specify more what "it does not work" means. That is not saying much (e.g. does your server has a bad day and it refuses the work?), better describe what exactly you expect and what exactly you get instead. E.g. by showing `var_dump()`s of important variables or picking error messages. Enable `WP_DEBUG` as well.